# Radeon settings causes system interrupts despite using Nvidia GPU

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon, interrupts

I am using Windows 10, AMD Ryzen 7 2700x CPU and Nvidia GPU. Lately, my desktop PC has been slowed down intermittently by system interrupts. From reliability history, I discovered that this was caused by Radeon settings software. See screenshow below

[image]

The strange thing is that I am using Nvidia GPU, not AMD GPU. Radeon is related to AMD GPU. I installed AMD chipset software because I'm using Ryzen 7 CPU.

Comment: it could be malware, genuine radeonsettings.exe is part of AMD's catalyst Control Center software, typically found in C:\Program Files\AMD\CNext\CNext\

Comment: From screenshot, radeonsettings.exe is located as what you pointed. So, not malware.

Comment: which makes me wonder why it is installed in the first place being an Nvidia graphics, look in programs and features list to see if CCC is installed.

Comment: @Moab, I suspect it came from "AMD chipset software". I installed this software because I'm using Ryzen 7 CPU.